# Where to turn off Data Server in Chrome for desktop

Tags: networking, google-chrome

Recently Google Chrome introduced Data Server feature which routes traffic from another place to make some optimizations and increase the speed.

I work with a website, that has cookie-based authentication. This optimization changes my IP address and User-Agent token, and once in a while I can't access the website and get *unauthorized access* error, due to the routing.

I can turn this feature off in Chrome for Android, but I can't find it on Chrome for Desktop. Where is it and how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this is just a regular extension. So:

> To disable it, click the Data Saver icon in the menu bar and choose
>   Turn Off Data Saver. Enable it again by clicking “Turn On Data Saver.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be a little checkbox on the upper right if you click on the Data Saver extension.

Click it off to turn off Data Saver temporarily.

[image]